# Ninject - (usercontrol) does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello: I've been successfully able to use Ninject with MVC 3/4 and the WCF Extensions. I am now trying to do a simple implementation with WebForms and ran into a challenge. The steps:

1. I downloaded the Ninject.Web from NuGet and installed into my WebForms project
2. I edited the NinjectWebCommon.cs -> CreateKernel method:

   ```
           kernel.Bind<ICasePresenter>().To<Presenter.CasePresenter>();
   ```
3. I edited my user control:

   ```
   [Inject]
   private ICasePresenter presenter;

   public CaseSummaryControl(ICasePresenter presenter)
   {
       this.presenter = presenter;
   }
   ```

I can see the breakpoint hit my binding but then I get the error that the user control does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments. It's not injecting my instance (even if I add a constructor with no arguments, the private var ends up being null.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the code of your parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You are using *field injection* instead of *constructor injection*.  Just move the `Inject` attribute to your constructor:

```
private ICasePresenter presenter;

[Inject]
public CaseSummaryControl(ICasePresenter presenter)
{
    this.presenter = presenter;
}
```

or add a constructor without the parameter:

```
[Inject]
private ICasePresenter presenter;

public CaseSummaryControl(ICasePresenter presenter)
{
    this.presenter = presenter;
}

public CaseSummaryControl()
{

}
```

That way you can keep the constructor with the parameter for unit testing.

The downside is you *may* need to add null-checks when you use `this.presenter` since you now have a path to create a `CaseSummaryControl` *without* specifying an `ICasePresenter`.

Read the [Ninject documenation](http://ninject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Injection%20Patterns) on the various injection patterns.

Comment: As the documentation states, I shouldn't have to use the [Inject] attribute at all (this is my previous experience with it). If I exclude it, though, no breakpoint is hit in CreateKernel(). I tried moving it to the constructor as you provided in your example and the breakpoint is hit, but I still get the no constructor error.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323489/argument-not-specified-for-parameter-using-ninject-in-web-forms, Web Forms does not support constructor injection, only field injection. Any confirmations on that? Field injection seems to work...

Comment: @MQuickel Added an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

**ASP.NET Webforms supports mostly PROPERTY based injections**. If you are using a constructor to define Injection then it simply throws error.

Here are the steps that you can follow as per today documentation

1. Install ***Ninject*** using ***Package Manager Console*** by typing **Install-Package Ninject.Web**.
2. Ninject should be installed now and you'll see a file named ***NinjectWebCommon.cs*** in the ***App_Start*** folder. Simply put your bindings there as already written by questioner.
3. Rather than creating a constructor create a public property in your calling class / method and use **[Inject]** attribute above it.

Compile your Application and dependencies should be created by now automatically.

You can see snapshot demonstration of these steps in another post [Using Ninject v3 in ASP.NET Web Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046162/how-to-inject-dependencies-using-ninject-in-asp-net-webform/40628073#40628073)