# How to inject dependencies using Ninject In ASP.NET WebForm?

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject, repository-pattern

I have a fair idea of using the Repository Pattern and have been attempting to "upgrade" our current way of creating ASP .Net websites. So i do the following

1. Create a solution with a class project called **DataAccessLayer** and another class project called **BusinessLogicLayer**. Finally a 3rd project which is my **ASP .Net website** (a normal site).
2. I add a dbml file to the DAL and drag a table, then in my BLL i add an interface and a class which implements this interface:

### My interface

```
namespace BLL.Interfaces
{
    interface IUser
    {
        List<User> GetAllUsers();
    }
}
```

### In my class

```
namespace BLL.Services
{
   public class UserService : BLL.Interfaces.IUser
    {
        public List<User> GetUsers()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I know the code is not fully completed, but there for illustrative purposes.

So i right click the BLL project > Manage NuGet Packages > Searched for Ninject and found a few. I was overwhelmed with the number of entries returned after after further research i am lost in how to add Ninject to a normal ASP .Net website? Specifically which addin i require? As there are many MVC and reading further i think im a little confused.

I was trying to add it to the BLL project as thats where i THINK it should go so i can *register my services* in there.

Could anyone guide me in what i need to so in order to use Ninject entries but im not using MVC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install [Ninject.Web](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web/) either from "Package Manager Console" or NuGet.

***Version is 3.2.1 as of this writing.***

[image]

OR

[image]

It will install the following 4 packages -

[image]

### Sample Service Class

```
public interface IUserService
{
    List<string> GetUsers();
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    public List<string> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<string> {"john", "eric"};
    }
}
```

Then add binding to `~/App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs`.

[image]

In code behind page, property inject using `[Inject]` attribute.

[image]

Comment: images are not really visible :)

Comment: @MahmoudHboubati Right click on an image, and select ***Open image in new tab*** *(in Chrome)*, ***View Image*** *(in Fire Fox)* or ***Save image as..*** *(in IE)*.

Answer (score 1):

**In Addition** in answer by **win** I would advise people not to get confused by using **Constructor based injection** in ASP.NET Webforms as **Web Forms doesn't support constructor based injection simply**. In default configuration they only support **Property based Injections** as already demonstrated by **Win**.