# ninject create NHibernate UnitOfWork only one time, every subsequent instantiation return previous UoW with closed session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, nhibernate, ninject

iam using ninject.web in my aspx page [in this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046162/how-to-inject-dependencies-using-ninject-in-asp-net-webform)

my problem is with Nhibernate session management.

this is my ninject module:

```
public override void Load()
{
    Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    Bind<IAttivitaRepository>().To<AttivitaRepository>();
}
```

the page_load and quite every button in a single page create and dispose a unit of work at this way:

```
using (iuow)
{
    iuow.DoSomething();
    iuow.SaveAll();
}
```

in pageLoad works, but every other attempt in the page to use iuow with a new Using block, return that session is closed

this is my UoW impl:

```
public UnitOfWork()
        {
            _nhHelper = new SessionFactory();
            InizializzaSessione();
            _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction();
        }

        private void InizializzaSessione()
        {
            if (_session == null)
            {
                _session = _nhHelper.OpenSession();
            }
            Area = new AreaRepository(this._session);
            Attivita = new AttivitaRepository(this._session);           
            Societa = new SocietaRepository(this._session);
            Persona = new PersonaRepository(this._session);         
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Salva le modifiche sulla base dati
        /// </summary>
        public void SaveAll()
        {
            if (_transaction != null)
            {
                _transaction.Commit();              
                _transaction = null;
            }
        }
```

it seems to me that iuow is resolved (whith a call to New) only at page load, so every new attempt to create Uow return last used one with session disposed.

before attimpting to use ninject what i do is simply:

```
using (Iuow = new UnitOfWork())
{
    ....
}
```

and all works fine

p.s.
i have to remove `InRequestScope` from binding since it prevent even the page load to work

Comment: I have never used ninject but surely the using statement is closing the session, remove this and close the session when you are finished.

Comment: i want that the new using block create a new UnitOfWork, not reuse existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
using (iuow)
{
    ...
}
```

by

```
using (IResolutionRoot.Get<IUnitOfWork>())
{
    ...
}
```

Whereas you can inject `IResolutionRoot` into your classes. No extra bindings necessary (it's a Ninject type).

Caveat: this is [service locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795459/is-servicelocator-an-anti-pattern).

Alternatively you can hide the `IResolutionRoot.Get<IUnitOfWork>()` behind an `IUnitOfWorkFactory` which you can either implement manually or use [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory) to do it for you.

### Example

```
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Syntax;

namespace NinjectTest.SO38013150
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork { }

    internal class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork { }

    public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
    {
        IUnitOfWork Create();
    }

    internal class UnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
    {
        private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

        public UnitOfWorkFactory(IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot)
        {
            this.resolutionRoot = resolutionRoot;
        }

        public IUnitOfWork Create()
        {
            return this.resolutionRoot.Get<IUnitOfWork>();
        }
    }
}
```

with a test showing that it works (this uses xunit for testing and FluentAssertions for assertions.. they are nuget packages):

```
using FluentAssertions;
using Ninject;
using Xunit;

namespace NinjectTest.SO38013150
{
    public class Test
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Foo()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
            kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWorkFactory>().To<UnitOfWorkFactory>();

            var factory = kernel.Get<IUnitOfWorkFactory>();

            var unitOfWork1 = factory.Create();
            var unitOfWork2 = factory.Create();

            unitOfWork1.Should().NotBeSameAs(unitOfWork2);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is also available as part of my examples collection, [here](https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/NinjectExamples/tree/master/NinjectTest/NinjectTest/SO38013150)

Comment: IUnitOfWorkFactory must be implemented in my Nhibernate project or it's a simple ninject encapsulation in web project of IResolutionRoot method?

Comment: @gt.guybrush It's a simple encapsulation of `IResolutionRoot.Get<IUnitOfWork>()` - just a few lines of code. Should be placed in the composition root = the web project.

Comment: i find kernel.Bind<IBarFactory>().ToFactory(); but think is not my case, other example mean creating an interface and a specific implementation, how can i do it in composition root?

Comment: find now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285946/ioc-ninject-and-factories i will try it

Comment: give error: IResolutionRoot does not contain definition for Get()

Comment: @gt.guybrush the low ratio of accepted answers to your questions don't motivate me to spoon-feed you a solution, especially given that very similar questions have been handled on SO before.

Comment: i always accept solution that resolve problem. when answer are useful but not resolutive i upvote them (and some of them are mine). at moment here i see only some non compiling code, even if it's an idea to follow. what's the similar question? i search a couple of days before making mine

Comment: @gt.guybrush i did a quick check and the search for "[ninject] unit of work factory" returns a lot of search results. Some of them even are relevant to what you're asking.. of course looking through all of these will take 1-4 hours of effort easily. Giving you the benefit of the doubt i have extended my answer with a complete working example, including `using` directives to make sure that that's not a stumbling block...

Comment: i was using it directly without creating an instance of IResolutionRoot. so in my app i have to use IUnitOfWorkFactory and not IUnitOfWork. that was what i misunderstood, I thought I could use iuow transparently and that ninject resolved it calling factory...

Comment: @gt.guybrush By convention, when something starts with an `I`, it's an interface - and interface never have fields/properties/methods which can be accessed statically. A search for `IResolutionRoot` would have shown that, too.

Comment: do you think that the module where i define all my repository binding can be a good place to keep this factory?

Comment: @gt.guybrush that's a good place to keep the binding of the factory. The factory interface should probably be where the `IUnitOfWork` interface is. The implementation should be in the web-application project.

Comment: ok. 
I was wondering a different idea: can be possible to hide factory to my web application? i ask for IUnitOfWork and ninject instead of calling the implementation calls a method thats do resolutionRoot.Get<IUnitOfWork>(). in that way don't need to remeber to call IuowFactory instead of Iuow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115786/discussion-between-batterybackupunit-and-gt-guybrush).

Comment: chat is locked by my office's proxy :( i can try Factory Methods with delegate, like the example Bind<IWeapon>().ToMethod(context => new Sword()); and ask new question if find problem

Comment: @gt.guybrush that doesn't make any sense at all. There still will be exactly **1** instance which can't be used as soon as it is `.Dispose()`d (which, incidentally, is what happens at the end of each `using` block!). You need a mechanism to create multiple instances per owner-object (page?). That's the factory - which is a replacement for the `new` operator.