# How can I use Ninject v3 in asp.net Web Forms?

Tags: asp.net, ninject, ninject.web

I am trying to use ninject version 3 in asp.net webforms application based on Jason answer

[How can I implement Ninject or DI on asp.net Web Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933695/how-can-i-implement-ninject-or-di-on-asp-net-web-forms/6121250)

but it is not working?

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
    {
........
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new NinjectWebCommon());
            return kernel;
        }
    }


public class NinjectWebCommon : NinjectModule
    {

        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
        }
    }
```

When I start debugging the CreateKernel never called and I get an exception NullReferenceException in the page that means no injection happened.

Comment: So what happens, or doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it work I removed the global.asax file as I don not need and add the NinjectWebCommon.cs
removed the references of ninject and added them again from nuget ( Ninject - Ninject.Web) and 
added my binding in App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IProductRepository>().To<EFProductRepository>();
        }
```

and in the page I used

```
[Inject]
        public IProductRepository Repository { get; set; }
```

and worked for me .