# Ninject solrnet binding doubts

Tags: ninject, solrnet

I am using Ninject for DI in my project. I am using solrnet for search functionality and I am trying to incorporate Solr to Ninject. Below is the code i have added in **Global.asax**

```
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        return new StandardKernel(new ServiceModule(), new SolrNetModule(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchServer"]));
    }
```

**SolrnetModule.cs**

```
public class SolrNetModule : NinjectModule 
{
    private readonly string serverURL;
    public IReadOnlyMappingManager Mapper { get; set; }

    public SolrNetModule(string serverURL)
    {
        this.serverURL = serverURL;
    }

    public override void Load()
    {
        var mapper = Mapper ?? new MemoizingMappingManager(new AttributesMappingManager());
        Bind<IReadOnlyMappingManager>().ToConstant(mapper);
        Bind<ISolrConnection>().ToConstant(new SolrConnection(serverURL));
        Bind(typeof(ISolrQueryResultParser<SolrSku>)).To(typeof(SolrQueryResultParser<SolrSku>));
        Bind(typeof(ISolrQueryExecuter<SolrSku>)).To(typeof(SolrQueryExecuter<SolrSku>));
        Bind(typeof(ISolrDocumentSerializer<SolrSku>)).To(typeof(SolrDocumentSerializer<SolrSku>));
        Bind(typeof(ISolrBasicOperations<SolrSku>)).To(typeof(SolrBasicServer<SolrSku>));
        Bind(typeof(ISolrOperations<SolrSku>)).To(typeof(SolrServer<SolrSku>));
        Bind(typeof(ISolrReadOnlyOperations<SolrSku>)).To(typeof(SolrServer<SolrSku>));
        Bind<ISolrService>().To<SolrService>();
    }
}
```

**Solrservice.cs**

```
 public class SolrService : ISolrService
 {
    public readonly ISolrReadOnlyOperations<SolrSku> _solr;     

    public SolrService(ISolrReadOnlyOperations<SolrSku> solr)
    {
        _solr = solr;
    }

    public ISolrQueryResults<SolrSku> SearchAll(string query)
    {
        var qopts = BuildParameters();
        var results = _solr.Query(query, qopts);
        return results;
    }

    private QueryOptions BuildParameters()
    {
        var qopts = new QueryOptions();
        qopts.AddOrder(new SortOrder("dateAdded", Order.DESC));
        return qopts;
    }
 }
```

While running the application, I am recieving the below error
"Error activating ISolrQuerySerializer

No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable."

Am i missing something here or the way i am trying to use Solr in NInject is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a custom SolrNetModule class, it appears that you have not connected up all of the required dependencies in the SolrNet stack for everything to run correctly. I would recommend using the [SolrNetModule](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Ninject.Integration.SolrNet/SolrNetModule.cs) that is provided with SolrNet. You can obtain this either from the [source](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/) or via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/SolrNet.Ninject/0.3.1). Alternatively, if you still want to use your own custom NinjectModule, I would reference the one from the source for comparison.

**Update:** Here is probably the best example of usage of Ninject with ASP.NET WebForms (I am assuming you are using ASP.NET WebForms based on your code structure)

- [How can I implement Ninject or DI on asp.net Web Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933695/how-can-i-implement-ninject-or-di-on-asp-net-web-forms)

Comment: Thanks Paige, I tried both the links, the sample code which they have defined in (SolrNet / Ninject.Integration.SolrNet.Tests / NinjectFixture.cs) contains initalization of Kernel( var c = new StandardKernel();), however my initalization happens in Global.asax. I need some sample code to call the Solr method. It would be helpful if you have any such code

Comment: Do you need an example of getting the solr instance from the Ninject kernel or of calling Solr in general?

Comment: I am good with the code for calling solr in general. I need the code to define the solr instance from Ninject kernel?

Comment: Updated with link to usage of Ninject within ASP.NET WebForms.