# what is the basic setting for run Ninject inside a asp.net(Webforms)

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, ninject

what is the basic setting for run Ninject inside a asp.net(Webforms) vb.net  webproject, I migrated a webproject  between .net framework 3.5 to 4.5 and I try to integrate Ninject to the new version of the  website, but the  WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod doesn't  run, I think in the migration I lost some special details and this details is required for run 
WebActivator , if I create a new WebApplication in VS 2015   and integrate WebActivator everything run very well, but with my migrated site doesn't  work, I lost some setting with the migration to 4.5, I need to know what I forget

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement Ninject or DI on asp.net Web Forms?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933695/how-can-i-implement-ninject-or-di-on-asp-net-web-forms)

Comment: I use WebActivatorEx, I convert a run the code in a new website and works very well, maybe a lost some detail in the  configuration when migrate the old code to a new framework, I need to know what all specials details for run ninject in webforms