# Dependency Injection in Asp.net WebForms 4.6.2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, webforms

Is it possible to implement constructor dependency injection with asp.net webforms 4.6.2?

Tried building the container in the Global.asax >> Application_Start method. However, I encountered the below error:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=4.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Yes, tried and getting error as 'Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=4.6.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ninject dependency resolver. It work's great in .net Web aplication. I think you can use it.
You can see the below link

[ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933695/how-can-i-implement-ninject-or-di-on-asp-net-web-forms)

Comment: That is correct. But, my team is using Autofac that's why.